# How can I most portably download via HTTP from a shell script? Can I rely on curl or wget?

Tags: shell, unix, curl, wget, portability

I want to write a portable shell script and runs on a variety of Linux systems, perhaps also other Unix systems (*BSD, macOS). That shell script needs to download files.

Which download tool is more to be expected to be available pre-installed by default? Curl or Wget?

Note that I'm not interested in which of both is currently "better" or more popular. Instead, I'm looking for the best long-term solution with as little code as possible.

Comment: That really depends on the age of the system. If you want to support really ancient systems, `wget` was more frequently preinstalled; more recently, that's shifting towards `curl`.

Comment: BTW, the reason this is a comment rather than an answer (maybe one with such a function included) is that this question is clearly off-topic; tool recommendation requests are outside our scope, and there's also been a longstanding hesitancy to support questions with answers that are likely to become outdated quickly or otherwise change over time. If instead you asked how to support both... *that* would be a good question, and one I'd be glad to answer. :)

Comment: ...so, I actually ended up writing such a tool (most of the complexity isn't actually from the curl/wget switch itself but around maintaining consistent behavior if the download fails), though it isn't an answer to the question as presently asked. See https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/475ca32feff3eb2ad1c1f0b62bd044ce -- and ping me if you edit the question or ask a new one where that *would* be a topical answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy In my opinion, "you need to support both" would be a perfectly valid answer to my question. Moreover, I don't care which of them is currently better, but I'm looking for the best long-term solution. So I hope that this question will have indeed long-term value. I just improved my question to make this more clear.

Comment: (BTW, it's *possible* to write a native-bash HTTP client, if targeting only shells where `/dev/tcp` is an enabled feature; that said, it would have its own portability challenges -- by depending on optional compile-time functionality -- and I'd probably start by looking at whether someone else had already done the work).

Comment: ...heh. The code quality is not great -- there are a bunch of subtle bugs in the scripts included (it's a very legitimate criticism of bash as a language that statements that look simple often have unintended behaviors until made longer and more complex to suppress those behaviors) -- but you may find https://github.com/fijimunkii/bash-dev-tcp of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to support a broad range of systems -- from old installations (which are more likely to support `wget`) to future ones (which are more likely to support `curl`), you really should support both.

This can be done with a shell function which checks which tool is available:

```
# usage: retrieve_url url
# results will be written to stdout
retrieve_url() {
  if command -v curl >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    curl --fail "$@"
  elif command -v wget >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    wget -O- "$@"
  else
    echo "ERROR: Unable to find either curl or wget" >&2
    exit 1
  fi
}
```

Given this general approach, it should be possible to extend it to support other tools as well -- such as falling through to run an embedded Python script running only standard-library code. (Issues that may be encountered in building a Python download script, suitable for embedding, that runs anywhere between Python 2.5 and through future 3.x releases are best asked separately, tagged for the appropriate community).